# Django Url in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, autocomplete

I am using jquery's `autocomplete` with ajax and django. The search feature exists on the navigation bar so it can be used from any url within the site. The issue I am running into is the link to be selected from the autocomplete dropdown. I have attempted passing in a django url like shown below in `main.js` but this leads to the url containing the characters '{% show_person %}' appended onto the end of the current url which obviously isn't the desire.

**main.js**: the success parameter within the ajax call.

```
...
success: function(a) {
                //console.log(a)
                $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: a,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        window.location.href = '{% url show_person %}';

                    },
                    minLength: 1,
                })
            }
```

Additionally, instead of the django url used above I have also tried `window.location.href = "person/"+ui.item.value;`. This ends up just appending `person/<personid>` onto whatever the current url is.

What I would like to happen is for the url to be mapped directly to the corresponding person's page, but this only works now if I am on the index page because there the url is empty and the appendage works.

Comment: You cannot do that in js file. But it can be done if your js code is in a template.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan any work arounds for in a js file?

Comment: I do not think so.... You have to hardcode this.